# PGFPlots: importing data from a txt file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So I imported data from two `txt` files.  However, I would like to plot the mean of the data and then the standard deviation bars.  How can this be done?

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}%                                                            
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}%                                                       
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{FRETData.txt}
\datatable%                                                                       
\pgfplotstableread{FRETData2.txt}
\datatabletwo%                                                                    
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymin = 0.16,
    ymax = 0.22,
    minor y tick num = 5,
    xmin = -6.7,
    xmax = -6.2
    ]
    \addplot table[y = 1] from \datatable;
    \addplot table[y = 1] from \datatabletwo;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the picture, we see that `pgfplots` has connected two separate experiments.  <s>How can I remove the line?</s>  Can `pgfplots` calculate the mean for each experiment and put standard deviation bars?

**Edit 1:**

So to remove the lines, I added only marks option.

Comment: My guess is that you should be using [box plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) instead.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `statistics` library shipped with `pgfplots`. I features `boxplots`.

Comment: @dustin, did the tip with the `boxplots` help you or do you need further assistance? In the first case I would close the question as being solved.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I don't remember this post is almost 3 years old.

Comment: Would you mind testing (again) and let us know? Or do you agree that we close the question as "unclear what you are asking"?

Comment: @StefanPinnow you don't close a question because it doesn't have an answer. Someone can always solve the problem later. If you want to you, you can answer it.

Comment: Of course I will not/cannot close the question, but I can *vote* to close it. I think you will agree that when somebody is asking a question and there are comments which might give a hint to the solution it is worth a try for OP to test it. Especially when there are (in sum) **5** upvotes to the comments.